# How to use a Google Earth with an overlay and filters

Tags: mysql, filter, overlay, google-earth

I am a designer who is in over his head.

I am trying to put a static Google Earth map into a MySQL database for a user to be able to login and access. I need the user to be able to click on several different filters and have the overlay change depending on the filters.

I have found some good tutorials on how to use Google Earth with PHP & MySQL. However, I can't find out how to use Google Earth with MySQL with custom filters.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't save the map,  save the user settings into the database.

2) As the user logs in, load the map and fetch the settings using AJAX

3) Based on the settings received use IF and Else and keep adding the markers, filters, overlays etc.

I have done something similar in a project where I show markers and info windows based on the user settings.. and on changing the settings, the settings are saved via ajax call and saved into the database..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am somewhat familiar with JavaScript, not so much with XML, and not at all with AJAX. Can you recommend a good tutorial?